# Loading worker file can't access from origin using laravel, vite and hot module replacment (hmr)

Tags: laravel, web-worker, vite, laravel-9, hot-module-replacement

i try to use web workers with vite and hot module replacement (hmr) and get the error that i can't access the JS file from my origin to the vite hmr server. But any access configs seems to be corrently configured.

`main.ts:25 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'http://localhost:5173/resources/js/core/engine/WorkerPoolWorker.js?type=module&worker_file' cannot be accessed from origin 'http://docker.magni-games.com'.`

I really doesn't have any clue anymore on how to fix this. I'm greatful for every idea!

main.ts:

```
const worker = new Worker(new URL("./core/engine/WorkerPoolWorker.js", import.meta.url), { type: 'module' }),
```

vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin"

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        hmr: {
            host: "localhost",
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                // "resources/sass/app.scss",
                "resources/js/main.ts",
            ],
            refresh: ["lang/**", "routes/**", "resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php"],
        }),
    ],
})
```

config/cors.php:

```
<?php

return [
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

Comment: OP, did you find a solution? Dealing with the same issue. Using 'vite watch' works, since the resources are then served from the same origin, but it would be nice if we could get it to work with the Vite dev server with HMR

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

Any success?

I was using workerize with laravel-mix, however after updating to laravel-vite, workers go broken.

I have tried using proxies, but did not succeed.

However, I could find a solution that may fit you, however, unfortunately does not fit me (I need to compile worker in typescript):

```
async function getWorker(url: Url) {
  let correct_url: string|URL;

  if(isProduction()) {
    correct_url = url;
  } else {
    const req = await fetch(url).then(resp => resp.blob());
    correct_url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  }

  return new Worker(correct_url, {
      type: 'module',
  })
}
```

P.S. tested only on dev server

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution yet? Dealing with exactly the same issue. The only solution that's working for now is running 'vite watch', since the assets then get served from the same origin. But getting it to work with HMR would be nicer